# Packet Buffer size in D-link DES-3552

Tags: d-link, buffer

What is the Packet Buffer size in D-link DES-3552?
I haven't found this information on any site (including official).

Comment: For whoever it is voting to close this, this is a layer 2 managed switch, not some SOHO DLink crap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has a 1 MB packet buffer, according to the product specifications on the [product page](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/support/product/des-3552-xstack-48-port-10-100-layer-2plus-managed-switch-2-gigabit-plus-2-combo).

```
10/100BASE-TX Ports
    48

10/100/1000BASE-T Stacking Ports
    2

Combo SFP Slots
    2

RS-232 Console Port
    Yes

Performance

Switch Capacity
    17.6Gbps

64-Byte Packet Forwarding Rate
    13.1 Mpps

MAC Address Table Size
    16K

Packet Buffer    
    1MB
```

[...]